# OGRSpatialReference works with proj4 string in GDAL 2 but not GDAL 3

Tags: gdal, proj, ellipsoid

I have the following proj string:

`+pm=greenwich +ellps=GRS80 +a=6.37814e+06 +rf=298.257 +proj=tmerc +units=m +to_meter=1 +lat_0=42.5 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +lon_0=-72.5 +k_0=0.999964 +vunits=m`

and I have an OGRSpatialReferenceObject.  When I call `SetFromUserInput()` on the string using GDAL-2.4.3, and then call `dumpReadable()`, the output starts with

```
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]
```

But when I do the same thing with GDAL-3.3.0, the output starts with

```
PROJCRS["unknown",                                                                                                                                                          
       BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",                                                                                                                                                      
            DATUM["unknown",                                                                                                                                                            
                ELLIPSOID["IAU 1976",6378140,298.257,                                                                                                                                       
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,                                                                                                                                                       
                        ID["EPSG",9001]]]],                                                                                                                                         
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,                                                                                                                                                       
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,                                                                                                                                      
                    ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
```

Why is GDAL-3.3.0 saying IAU 1976 instead of GRS 1980?   Later on, this OGRSpatialReference object is computing the central meridian and false northing to both be zero (which is wrong), while the GDAL-2.4.3 version gets it right.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by having both +ellps and {+a, +rf} specified. Only one should be given.